# close ngx-color-picker when focus tab out

Tags: angular, accessibility, color-picker

I tab into anchor tag and it opens my 'ngx-color-picker' component, after that when I press tab again then I focus out from the anchor tag and move the focus to my next input tag.
While moving the focus to next input tag I want to close the 'ngx-color-picker' component.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Please find stackblitz url to check for the issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfsvkq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Please provide a Minimum Viable Example, via stackblitz or other sandbox for angular. Thanks!

Comment: Please find below Stalkblitz url for your reference, when color-picker is open on second input tag and I pressed tab key then it should close color-picker before focusing to third input tag

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfsvkq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html